# How to read _csv.reader object?

Tags: python, csv, text, ascii, csvreader

I have a `_csv.reader` type object that has been created by a function gathering data from an API. How would I open and parse this type of object, for processing in Pandas etc?

The object was initially created in this way:

```
obj = csv.reader(io.BytesIO(Results.encode('ascii', 'replace')), delimiter='\t')
```

Comment: Yes but it did not work. Trying to iterate through the object gives:
Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

Comment: Ok, the error messge seems pretty self-explanatory... why are you passing a `io.BytesIO` object instead of a `io.StringIO`? the reader object requires strings, not bytes

Comment: What is a `_csv.reader`? From the prefix it looks like a private attribute.

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga changing to stringIO worked (see edit). Doing the same with the BytesIO object would be nice to know but not necessary

Comment: @littlefield you can't, `csv` reader objects require strings.

Answer (score 0):

Changing to StringIO worked. I believe BytesIO was used due to the encoding, possibly to ignore greek characters?

with io.StringIO(Results) as file:
csv_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter='\t')
for row in csv_reader:
print(row)

Comment: "I believe BytesIO was used due to the encoding, possibly to ignore greek characters?" No, almost certainly, you were looking at an old example (Python 2)